# How replacing with regex characters generated by encoding errors when embedded in text

Tags: regex, r, gsub

I need to replace the following characters with regex (gsub):

`ÃÆÃÂ¨` -> è
`ÃÆÃÂ`  -> à
`ÃÆÃÂ²` -> ò
`ÃÆÃÂ¬` -> ì
`ÃÆÃÃ¹` -> ù

My strategy is to first remove the first three characters `ÃÆÃ` that are common to all and the move to the last, leaving *à* at the end since it is basically the lowest common denominator. 
Now gsub correctly removes the first three but then it seams it doesn't see the final ones - like `Â¨` - but I noticed it sees `Ã±` (for *ñ*).

By copy/pasting the characters into the text editor I noticed they cause weird behaviours (such as moving the cursor forward by few positions).

My dataset was downloaded from a website that itself has encoding problems for the oldest pages but not for the most recent ones (I think they corrected the encoding problem sometime in the last years). Visiting the oldest pages you can still see the very same ÃÆÃÂ¨ in plain sight. Then the problem is not (I assume) in the encoding of my file.

That is, the encoding errors are limited to regions of the dataset and are not the result of an encoding issue with the whole text corpus.

Comment: This is an encoding problem, not a regex problem.

Comment: You can use Encoding to convert them into UTF-8:  Encoding(your-string) <- "UTF-8"

Comment: I tried Encoding(x). Didn't work. See my edits.

Comment: You may post a link here for the website

Comment: OK, my solution was to check how the characters exactly appear in the R console. It could be something like `Ã\u0083Æ\u0092Ã\u0082Â¨`. Then copy paste that: `gsub("Ã\u0083Æ\u0092Ã\u0082Â¨"...`

Comment: @CptNemo, although this is an encoding problem in the origin, it would be helpful to know how to remedy this using regex, so please consider posting an answer to your own question with more details of your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem when the characters are not correctly displayed is to understand exactly how they are parsed by the regex. In my case, as explained, the encoding errors where limited to few strings in my dataset. Then Encoding() was not applicable.

I solved the problem by visualising the problematic characters directly in R console. In console they appear like `Ã\u0083Æ\u0092Ã\u0082Â¨` while in the R-studio they were visualised as `Ã Æ Ã Â¨`. What visualised in console was what I needed for a correct match with regex: gsub("Ã\u0083Æ\u0092Ã\u0082Â¨"...